# Call NAG subroutine in Mathematica 10

Tags: interoperability, fortran

Is there any package or any other way to call or use [`NAG library`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAG_Numerical_Library)?

It was possible in old mathematica?

Comment: Perhaps you should specify what in particular you are attempting to do. Then you could be directed to the particular functions that have the functionality you are seeking.

Comment: Which particular NAG routine were you interested in? We might be able to suggest a *Mathematica* equivalent you could try first.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I am interested in subroutine D01FCF.

Comment: Particularly I am interested in multidimensional integral with the dimension 4 or 5 or even more. For example there are 4 dimensions. x1,x2,x3,x4 in which limit of x4 ->(0,1-x1-x2-x3), x3->(0,1-x1-x2), x2->(1-x2),x1->(0,1). The regular method is not useful.

Comment: Might be useful to show the actual integral. `NIntegrate` has numerous settings that can be used to influence the outcome, and there are people on this forum with some level of experience in using it.

Comment: That particular routine apparently uses Genz-Malik, which is also supported in *Mathematica*. Do post your actual integral; as Daniel says, it is possible that `NIntegrate[]` can be coaxed to fill your needs.

Comment: my integral is of type 
$$
\int_0^1 dx_1\int_0^{1-x1} dx_2\int_0^{1-x1-x2}dx_3\int_0^{1-x1-x2-x3} dx_4  f(x1,x2,x3,x4)
$$

Comment: This is an integral over a simplex, no? You might want to look up the region-related functionality of `NIntegrate[]`; you can use `Simplex[]` as a region specification.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. In my particular case the simplex method can work. I found the similar case on [math](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459555/integrate-function-over-3-simplex). but still this method is not giving any numerical result. if i am having the condition 
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 1
$$
then can we convert the dimension of integration from 4 to 3?